Importance of Logical Notation
Does better notation lead to ease of abstraction and shorter proofs? I ask because I tried translating the following from Euclid’s Elements into my own idiosyncratic notation: Prime numbers are more than any assigned multitude of prime numbers. This can be translated as follows:

A=X is a set
B=X is finite
C=X contains only prime numbers
D=Y is prime
E=Y has the property of not being contained in X
∀X∃Y(ABC→DE)
Note, (6) should be translated as thus: For all X there exists Y such that if X is a set, is finite, and contains only prime numbers, then Y is prime and Y has the property of not being contained in X. All you would have to do prove (6) is to show that its negation is unsatisfiable. Or if the negation is satisfied, it would lead to a contradiction. Note, my idiosyncratic notation was inspired by Boole’s use of multiplication for conjunction and addition for disjunction.


Wrt "better notation" in general, the impressive development of modern mathematics in Early Modern Europe is due to the invention of algebraic symbolism and its later modification to be applied to calculus.

Specificlly regarding your attempt, you have to use predicate logic.

@AUTISTINC "Prime numbers are more than any assigned multitude of prime numbers." If that's a quote from Euclid, could you please give a reference which also shows the context ; thanks.

@JoWehler, here’s the reference: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIX/propIX20.html

@JoWehler - the meaning is simply: assume that there are n prime numbers: p1, p2, ..., pn; then there is a prime p(n+1) that is different from (and strictly greater than) all the previous ones.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, couldn’t it be translated another way though?

@AUTISINC Thanks, now I see what Euclid means. He means: For each finite number of primes there is a bigger prime. It is not difficult to understand the meaning of this statement. And I do not see that what you call your "idiosyncratic notation" is better.

Do you mean the text? or the symbols? The main issue is that you are using quantifiers but you are evoiding to use the variable to be quantified in the corersponding predicates, and this can be quite confusing with compelx statements.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, I see what you mean. I wrote the OP that way because it’s more convenient for me to view it that way.

If you are specifically interested into Euclid, see Ian Mueller, Philosophy of Mathematics and Deductive Structure in Euclid’s Elements (1981, MIT Press).

@MauroALLEGRANZA, by translate, I mean translating Euclid’s words into predicate logic or my variant of predicate logic.

@JoWehler I believe the statement is not that there is a bigger prime, but that if you have any number n, there are more than n primes. The proof goes by starting with a collection of n primes (the "assigned multitude") and constructing a new and different one.

@DavidRoberts I agree with you. - The non-existence of a biggest prime then follows from Euclid's statement at once.
